# OpenSSH problem. works ok first time after install. Then goes crazy

Tags: networking, server, ssh, openssh

I'm trying to set up a new server, just a basic one with openssh.
First I tried a regular installation with Ubuntu server and installed openssh along with the server-install.
First time I tried to connect with standard config-file and got

```
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:uWdXv1DYZ+MmnFOtYadTAPEZj93uculj8a4OZ5lnEOk.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

Then the connection was normal.
Then I tried to connect again like 1 hour later and got

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:B12I+ERcLf+RMREsqxTpy8J5KyoqvsXLbijtz5TUMDw.
Please contact your system administrator.Add correct host key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:5
```

I did the `ssh-keygen -f "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"`
Then tried again

```
The authenticity of host 'ip-adress' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:B12I+ERcLf+RMREsqxTpy8J5KyoqvsXLbijtz5TUMDw.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

Then goes to

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@server's password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

And then denied permission again for 2 more times.

I've read the man-pages on openssh and googled and tried the normal stuff like edited the `sshd_config` to only allow password, host-auth, edited out the identity for keys etc. and nothing works. 
So I've tried reinstalling the openssh, same problem. Tried setting up a new server with desktop-ubuntu, same problem. Works the first connection, then goes crazy. Tried debian, same. Tried older version of Ubuntu, same problem. I actually got 1 server-install to function for some tries, but after 15sec i got broken pipe all the time. But I didn't get the permission denied.

I was wondering, what happens to openssh between the first connection and the rest?
How can I fix this?
Seems like the server is shutting me out, it doesn't even tries to let me connect.

Answer (score 1):

When you connect to your server for first time, ssh asks you to verify the fingerprint of the server with this question:

`Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes`

And when you answer it with yes, it will create a file in ~/.ssh directory named: `known_hosts` and puts your server identities there for next times.

Whenever something changes in your server that impacts its identity (for example: serve IP address), you will receive this message, because ssh client thinks that you are not connecting to the correct server. (based on the data that lives in `known_hosts`).

You can remove the old identity data from `known_hosts` with this command:

```
ssh-keygen -R [IP ADDRESS - OR HOST NAME OF SERVER]
```

Then try to connect again.

**How to verify server identity:**
If you have direct access to the server, for example if it's a VM, you can run:

```
ssh-keyscan -t ecdsa localhost > ssh.ecdsa 2> /dev/null
ssh-keygen -lf ssh.ecdsa
```

It will give you something like:

```
256 SHA256:0MY+7jktivMDvak0Clfkk49fkgjDbhWYrQBT//BsF5YDoV4 192.168.1.14 (ECDSA)
```

Now when using ssh you can verify that you are connecting to the correct server or not.

Comment: Thanks for reply. "And when you answer it with yes, it will create a file in ~/.ssh directory named: known_hosts and puts your server identities there for next times." Ive already done this, and the file was generated correctly, and the list had other entries in it as well. This is not first time the client uses ssh. And when i set up a new server with same ip i removed the old identity ofcourse. And nothing on the server changed, so why did it ask for a new identity? I did verify the server identity, its ok

Comment: Temporary rename `known_hosts` file, see if anything changes. How your server gets an IP? I've seen DHCP being the the cause of problem.

Comment: Are you connecting via hostname or IP? Check if the hostname still resolves to the correct IP.